# operation in data table

Tags: vb.net, datatable

I want to select a range of data from my data table ,

I have tried in datatable.Select() method.

Consider, i have 10 rows of data in **dtExcelSource**  and now filter from the 4th row and insert records from 5th row till last row.

Am coding in vb.Net

```
     dtExcelSource = DS.Tables("SourceTbl")

            dtExcelSource.Columns(0).ColumnName = "A"
            dtExcelSource.Columns(1).ColumnName = "B "
            dtExcelSource.Columns(2).ColumnName = "CNo"
            dtExcelSource.Columns(3).ColumnName = "DNo"
            dtExcelSource.Columns(4).ColumnName = "E"
            dtExcelSource.Columns(5).ColumnName = " F"

            Dim filterDT As DataTable = dtExcelSource.Clone()
            Dim rows As DataRow() = dtExcelSource.[Select](???)
            For Each row As DataRow In rows
                filterDT.ImportRow(row)
            Next

            gridView.datasource = filterDT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need to use `For Loop` instead of `For Each`, Also you dont need the `SELECT` if you used it just to filter by row number:

```
    For iRowNo As Integer = 3 To dtExcelSource.Rows.Count - 1
        filterDT.ImportRow(dtExcelSource.Rows(iRowNo))
    Next
```

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
For Each row As DataRow In dtExcelSource.Rows
  If *your range criteria*
    filterDT.ImportRow(row)
  End If
Next
```